# Where can I see the standard salary range for California State University Assistant Professor?

Tags: job, tenure-track, salary

Is there a website where I can see the standard salaries for recently hired tenure track Assistant Professors in California State University system? I am on the job market and almost in the process of getting an offer. I wanted to get an idea of what to expect and negotiate.

EDIT: it is California State University system.

Comment: What's CSU? California State? Colorado State? Cleveland State?

Comment: Probably varies with number of publications, years of experience and size of ego... Also, many places won’t always publish that information...

Comment: @SolarMike: Does that mean if I develop a huge ego I get a pay raise?

Comment: @einpoklum Probably depends on how you argue and what **you** think you are worth... some discussions "never the twain shall meet”...

Comment: @SolarMike Not only are public schools in the US required to publish a pay scale, they usually a required to publish individual salaries. This is a result of being a government institution funded by tax dollars.

Comment: @user71659 define "usually" - so this information is available or to a limited few or a range of salary is published... or does "usually" mean when they get around to it ie the last available figures are from 2005? Well 2017 as per another comment - what happened to 2018 salaries - not paid yet so they don’t know...

Comment: @SolarMike It's a matter of state law and how the institution is set up with regards to being a government organization. There is also an interaction with student privacy rights. See the answers for a link to California's disclosure.

Comment: @user71659 so if it invades privacy then they don’t have to publish... As I pointed out "many places won’t always publish that information" ... round and round the mulberry bush for not a lot...

Comment: @SolarMike Nope, nearly all non-student salaries are published. Go see the link. I stand by what I say, "many places won’t always publish that information" is simply incorrect for public US schools due to government disclosure requirements in this country.

Comment: @user71659 You first stated that they all have to publish, now you are hedging your bets... So stand by both sides...

Comment: Field also matters.

Comment: @SolarMike Typically, all you get in the US is a giant spreadsheet of everyone, their title, and salary. Sometimes news agencies pretty this up for you. For all the universities I've ever looked up, they're usually reasonably on time (six months to a year after the conclusion of the year in question). I have never heard of a restriction on releasing student wages. In fact, I just checked, and found my wages from my undergraduate years. Obviously I don't know the laws of every state, but I think its fair to say US public universities have to publish individual salaries more often than not.

Comment: I have no idea why this question would be closed. This is a request for a fact - where is this information? - and the fact is supplied in the answers. Vote to reopen.

Comment: @AzorAhai [UC](https://ucannualwage.ucop.edu/wage/) withholds student pay. "Pursuant to federal student privacy laws, the names of all employees whose employment was dependent upon student status (including medical residents) at any point during a given calendar year have been redacted and appear as ******."

Comment: @user71659 Interesting. I guess I was hired into a role that didn't define me as a student.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm just assuming you mean California State University since it's the largest system among the states starting with "C", which can be found here:

https://transparentcalifornia.com/salaries/california-state-university/

You can search individuals by name. If the university or university system is public, then the information for faculty/staff salaries is usually posted on some government or independent auditing site.

Comment: 1. You cannot find standard salaries there, only individual salaries. 2. They don't sort academic faculty by rank or status. 3. For 2017, you see a scale of figures from 0 to 274,088 USD / annum - as the base pay. What does this tell you? Not much... -1 on this answer.

Comment: OP can look at the desired department's faculty directory, look for tenure-track assistant professors, and search them up on the database. There are large discrepancies in Assistant Prof positions among departments (e.g., English vs. Business), so standard salaries won't tell you much either and may even result in OP under or overestimating their projected salary.

Comment: Absolutely agree with @ssjjaca . Should base this on professors that are "like them", hired in the same departments or similar, etc. A "standard" won't tell them important information.

Comment: @ssjjaca What do they mean by "other pay"? Any idea?

Comment: @math Summer pay. You only get 9 regular paychecks for an academic year appointment. Grant support or summer teaching optionally covers the rest. For medical faculty, it includes the money they receive from patients for performing procedures. It may also include certain pay increments/bonuses for administrative duties.

Answer (score 3):

### TL;DR It's between $4,923 and $10,924 USD / month

I'm also assuming you mean the California State University system.

Well, CSU have a [Salary Schedule database](http://www.calstate.edu/HRAdm/SalarySchedule/Salary.aspx), which you can search. The appropriate search term seems to be [FACULTY](http://www.calstate.edu/HRAdm/SalarySchedule/SalaryGrid.aspx?S1=1&F1=FACULTY&D1=0&Page=1&Recs=50). This gets you a whole number of records, with different qualifications for programs, disciplines etc. But the basis-of-the-basis is:

> ```
> Class Range   Effective Date  Class Title                             Min Salary  Max Salary  CBID    Status
> 2360  3       2018-10-31      INSTRUCTIONAL FACULTY - ACADEMIC YEAR   $4,923.00   $10,924.00  R03 Active
> ```

and if you click through the position code, as @user71659 suggests, you get to [this page](http://www.calstate.edu/HRAdm/SalarySchedule/SalaryDetail.aspx?S1=1&F1=FACULTY&D1=0&Page=1&Recs=50&Rk=23603181031&Rn=48&Rt=162). It tells you this position is that of an Assistant Professor for the Academic Year. It also has the pay scale.

Note that even then the database shows a salary *range*, i.e. a minimum and maximum salary. I have no idea what determines where in the range you end up. Perhaps it's  managerial flexibility in hiring? Who knows.

You can also contact their (general) HR department and verify, or be more specific (department, program etc.): Their phone is (562) 951-4411 and there's also a [web contact form](http://www.calstate.edu/emailcontact.asp?q=hr1).

Comment: Normal professors are "INSTRUCTIONAL FACULTY - ACADEMIC YEAR", you can see how they map to assistant/associate/full via the Abbreviated Class Title. Like most positions, note that you only get paid 9 months of the year.

Comment: @user71659: 1. What is the "abbreviated class title?"  2. There are multiple qualifications for programs, disciplines etc. so it's difficult (for me) to tell that there's an obvious default OP is interested in.

Comment: The question is missing information (even what "C" means), but this is the "normal" professorship. Click through on a class and you see "abbreviated class title" in the upper right, i.e. 2360 range 4 is "ASSOC PROF AY" [Academic Year]

Comment: @user71659: Right you are.

Comment: @einpoklum This range from $4,923 to $10,924, seems very wide. What determines where one stands in this range?

Comment: @MorganRodgers Ok, they must have changed it at some point. I know UC stretches your academic year pay over 12 months, I'm fairly certain CSU used to not pay over the summer (and they wouldn't even let faculty park on campus).

Comment: How usual is it to find courses to teach in summer? Is it competitive or first come first serve?